# State machine event by condition doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, lambda, state-machine

I need a state_machine event to provide transitions only if a given parameter (code) matches object attribute (temporary_code).

When I test this code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def initialize
    @temporary_code = 'right'
  end

  state_machine :initial => :inactive do
    event :activate! do
      transition :inactive => :active, :if => lambda{ |code| code == @temporary_code }
    end

    state :inactive do
      def active?
        false
      end
    end

    state :active do
      def active?
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't make a transition whatever code is given. Rspec test below returns an error:

```
describe "activation" do
  let(:user) { User.create }
  before { user.activate!('right') }
  specify { user.should be_active }
end
```

What wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

When you reference an instance variable like `@temporary_code`, you always get a result, even if it hasn't been mentioned/defined/initialized yet. So what I think is happening is that you reference `@temporary_code`, but that it is always `nil`, because the lambda assigned to `:if` is not executed in the context of an instance of User, but rather within an instance of the class into which the state machine has been 'compiled'.

Now there's something strange in your code: you have defined

```
transition :inactive => :active, :if => lambda {|code| code == @temporary_code}
```

but what is passed to the lambda is in fact the current `user`. So

```
transition :inactive => :active, :if => lambda {|user| ... }
```

would be more appropriate.

As far as I know the state_machine gem doesn't provide a direct way to make transitions depend on parameters. So I think you should take it outside and add the following to the User class:

```
attr_accessor :temporary_code
attr_accessor :code
```

then change the transition to

```
transition :inactive => :active, 
           :if => lambda {|user| user.code == user.temporary_code}
```

and have the code that calls `activate!` first set the `temporary_code`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, when I use
 
    event activate! ..., :if => lambda{ |user| ... }
 
And then try to call it without parameters (supposing current object will be given by definition)

    user.activate!()
 
I receive an error "wrong number of parameters (0 for 1)".

Now (as a temporary solution) I've decided to move authorization to upper level by adding class activate (without bang), where "activate!" called by condition. But it isn't an ideal method because of security hole, which I tryed to avoid. :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. It sounds like you have defined a separate `activate!` method that takes a single parameter?